# Angular filter search unexpected results

Tags: angularjs, search

Hi I'm new to this framework, and have to make some changes to current wepapp.
There is a two-way binding like this:

```
<input type="text" class="catalog-search input input--large input--full" ng-model="search.rodzina" placeholder="Szukaj...">
```

and nested ul list.

```
<ul class="catalog-list catalog-scroll">
  <li ng-repeat="rodzic in list | groupBy:'styl' | toArray:true | orderBy:!'$key'">
    <strong>{{rodzic.$key}}</strong>
      <ul class="">
        <li ng-repeat="dziecko in rodzic | filter:search | bookmark:search" ng-class="{active:isActiveTab(dziecko)}" ng-click="openItem(dziecko)">
         {{dziecko.rodzina}}&nbsp;
          <b>{{dziecko.page}}</b>
            </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Sample JSON object:

```
{"id":1252,"nazwa":"Otwarcie","foto":"katalog_2015\/000.jpg","visible":0,"cat_id":7,"strona":1,"styl":"Wst\u0119p","rodzina":"Otwarcie","kod":"Ok\u0142adka","bookmark":true,"title":"Wst\u0119p Otwarcie","page":1,"image":"\/gazetka\/katalog_2015\/000.jpg","width":1412,"height":1998,"tags":"Wst\u0119p Otwarcie Ok\u0142adka Otwarcie"}
```

JS - there is no special method for searching already just simple two-way binding

I want to search only by 'rodzina' property so I set ng-model="search.rodzina".
Unfortuantely the search results include also empty parent names with names, and this is very inconvenient to the end user.

How can I improve filtering to match only words that I'm looking for?
Here is link for that app:
http://redhand.lemir.iq.pl/pl/g7,Katalog-2015

Comment: You should post up some of you angular code also so that users can see what else is going on. Possibly some sample data would be helpful also.

Comment: I did some changes to my post above

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like to exclude, in the outer ng-repeat, the "rodzics" who have no child "dziecko " element displayed by the inner ng-repeat, is that right? If so, write a filter which does that, and apply it to the first ng-repeat.

Comment: I want to see in the results only items that match word I typed, for example 'zwisy'. Check link I put above.

Comment: As I said: you need to write a filter for the outer ng-repeat. The filter needs to return true if the filtered children has at least one element, and false if not. Shouldn't be hard. Try something.

Comment: OK, so inside controller I should implement some function,that take in object? And then add filter: nameFunction to parent li or filter:search:funcName ?